# es6 Loop through object array and aggregate unique values from key pair (cleanest way)

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

What's the cleanest and es6 native (if possible) way to loop through a object array to grab each unique value.  Example would like this :

```
[{
"name" : "joe",
},
,{
"name" : "jean",
},
{
"name" : "joe",
},
{
"name" : "joe",
},
{
"name" : "mike", 
}]
```

and in my results I want to see only : joe, jean, mike (only unique values, no dupes)

Answer (score 5):

Since you mentioned ES6, it seems like a Set object would be what you want since it will do the uniqueness part for you and should do so fairly efficiently:

```js
var objs = [{"name" : "joe"},{"name" : "jean"},{"name" : "joe"},{"name" : "joe"},{"name" : "mike"}];

let uniqueNames = Array.from(new Set(objs.map(item => item.name)));
console.log(uniqueNames);
```

Run this snippet to see the results.

Answer (score 3):

```js
a = [{name:"joe"},{name:"jean"},{name:"joe"},{name:"joe"},{name:"mike"}]

console.log(_.uniq(_.map(a, 'name')))           // Lodash 0.1.0

console.log([...new Set(a.map(o => o.name))])   // ES6
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var objs = [{"name" : "joe"},{"name" : "jean"},{"name" : "joe"},{"name" : "joe"},{"name" : "mike"}];
var uniqueNames = objs.map( obj => obj.name )
  .filter( (name, idx, arr) => { return arr.indexOf(name) === idx; } );
```

The `.map` extracts an array of the name values, and the `.filter` returns only the unique elements (first instances only).

Comment: fantastic, beautiful and simple